# How to properly import flutter project from VSCode to Android Studio to do a Gradle Sync?

Tags: android, gradle, visual-studio-code

I have created a flutter project on VSCode `flutter create bmi` and when I try to import it to Android Studio 4.1.1. But I can't use `Sync Project With Gradle Files` in Android studio. It does not even give me the option to `Sync Project With Gradle Files` at start.

I tried the new feature `Import Project (Gradle, Eclipse ADT, etc)`. Then it gave me the option to sync but on selecting the option it keeps giving me the issue

[image: pic]

And even if I create a flutter project on Android Studio I still need to import it again to show me the `Sync Project With Gradle Files` option but it will still give me that error.

Some solution suggest on internet that

```
You should have setting.gradel file in the top folder to do a sync
```

But flutter always create it in andriod folder. Maybe I understood it wrong.

And 2nd there is no `Android` option here
[image]

But I am thinking this issue will be resolved after the sync.

Answer (score 0):

After long research, there was only one way to do `Sync Project With Gradle Files` that is

> Open the `Andriod folder` and find the `setting.gradle` file.

> Open the file in the new window of android studio.

Now you can see the `Sync Project With Gradle Files` option. But it still gave me a new error `Gradle Sync Failed`.

I am using Andriod Studio 4.1.1.